# Quick Java inheritance

Tags: java

Ok so just practicing questions from my textbook for Christmas finales but I sometimes don't understand what some of the questions want.

I'm a bit lost,does it want me to inherit Email tester class?

**Question :** 
*Create a class EmailTester with a main
method which uses the Message class to make a
message and print it.*

```
public class Message{    
    String rep;
    String send;
    String mess = "message";


    public Message(String rep,String send){
        rep = "recipient";
        send = "sender";
        mess="";

    }
    public  void append(){          
        mess = " "+"blah blah";         
    }

    public String toString(){           
        mess = "From: Santa Clause\nTo: Rudolf Reindeer\n . . ."; 
        return mess;
    }
}
```

--

```
public class EmailTester {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //?
    }    
}
```

Comment: It wants you to create an instance of `Message` and use it.

Comment: Your `Message` constructor ignores it's parameters. Take a closer look at it.

Comment: oh...come on, just learn some OOP, or get an example from miriads of examples from internet, this is a ##$$# question for this site :(

Comment: Oh so sorry for not knowing,how is one to learn without asking questions..

Comment: @Rodislav, even you were once a beginner asking people "##$$# questions." If it bothers you that much, why did you click on a question called *Quick Java inheritance* in the first place? What did you expect? An exposition on the Liskov Substitution Principle? The OP is a beginner. Let him or her ask and learn.

Comment: "my textbook for Christmas finales" --> just read everything, this is a work he has to do, if he can - he should read and learn, you want to say on the internet we don't have enough books !? just deploy yourselves in your servers :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your constructor to look like this:

```
public Message(String recipient, String sender){
        this.recipient = recipient;
        this.sender = sender;
        body = "";
}
```

The variable names don't matter, but I think they are more intuitive. The main point is that you want each *instance* of `Message` to store the values used to construct it.

Then in `EmailTester`, you do something like this:

```
Message m = new Message("recipient", "sender");
```

You will have to ask your professor what it means to "send" a message in this context.

As for inheritance, I have no idea how it applies. Perhaps your instructor is looking to expand things in a future exercise so you have different kinds of messages.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need something so complicated as inheritance. If your course was any good, you should have learned about creating objects first, and inheritance later, because inheritance makes no sense without first understanding creating simple objects!

```
String output = new Message("foo", "bar").toString();
```

then print that String.

Comment: It won't print out foo nor bar though, if you don't fix that constructor first.

Answer (score 0):

A class should inherit another class only when it shares "is a relationship".

- EmailTester is a Message : Does not sound correct
- Suppose if there is an Email class then, Email is a message - sounds correct

So in your case, no need to extend Message class, rather create an instance of Message class and do the needful.

Answer (score 0):

Message message = new Message("blah", "blah"):

Answer (score 0):

`EmailTester with a main method which uses the Message class to make a message and print it.`

Clearly it states **has a** relationship(composition). `EmailTester` has a `Message`. No inheritance is required.

Inheritance is applied when you can sense **is a** relationship. e.g Car and Vehicle.